# Angular не видит динамических изменений в папке assets

Tags: angular, assets

Ситуация: в проекте есть папка с фотографиями называется assets.

Если в папке есть фотографии на которые ссылаются img теги, то эти фотографии будут отображены, соответственно если фотографии нету, она не будет отображена на клиенте.

Все логично, но, если эту фотографию загрузить в папку, и перезагрузить страничку, она не появиться. Более того если удалить из папки отображенные фотографии, и перезагрузить страницу, они не исчезнут.

Но если, перекомпилировать клиент, то изменения в папке вступают в силу. Такое ощущение, что ангулар не отслеживает изменения в папке.

Задача: помогите исправить это поведение. Я пробовал очищать кэш при перезагрузке страницы, и включать prodMode, но ничего не поменялось. Проект написан с использованием asp.net core 2.1.

Вряд ли проблема в коде, но всё-таки вот.

Код home.component.html:

```
<p *ngIf="!placementlist"><em>Loading...</em></p>

<div class="placements-image">
        <img src="../../assets/placements.png" style="height: 40px">
  </div>

<div *ngIf="placementlist" class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8 div-main">
      <div *ngFor="let placement of placementlist" class="div-placement row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <img src="{{placement.mainphoto}}" style="width: 230px;">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <h3>{{ placement.header }}</h3>
          <p>placement type: {{ placement.type }}</p>
          <p>placement location: {{ placement.location }}</p>
          <a href="http://localhost:3000/details">
            <button id="{{ placement.id }}" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" (click)="details($event)" >Detail information</button>
         </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="menu">
          <h3>Menu</h3>
          <a href="http://localhost:3000/placementform">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">New offer</button>
        </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Код home.component.ts:

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent {
  public placementlist = [];
  constructor(http: HttpClient, @Inject('BASE_URL') baseUrl: string) {
    http.get<Placement[]>(baseUrl + 'api/home/main').subscribe(result => {
      this.placementlist = result;
    }, error => console.error(error));
  }

  details(event)
  {
    console.log("details");
    var target = event.target || event.srcElement || event.currentTarget;
    var attribute = target.attributes.id;
    var idvalue = attribute.nodeValue;
    idvalue = idvalue - 1;
    console.log('target element have id ' + idvalue + ', initializing details component');
    //index must have -1 correction couse of call placement INDEX,
    //but not element PROPERTY

    sessionStorage.setItem("header", this.placementlist[idvalue].header);
    sessionStorage.setItem("mainphoto", this.placementlist[idvalue].mainphoto);
    sessionStorage.setItem("type", this.placementlist[idvalue].type);
    sessionStorage.setItem("location", this.placementlist[idvalue].location);
    sessionStorage.setItem("entity", this.placementlist[idvalue].entity);
    sessionStorage.setItem("size", this.placementlist[idvalue].size);
    sessionStorage.setItem("fromDate", this.placementlist[idvalue].fromDate);
    sessionStorage.setItem("toDate", this.placementlist[idvalue].toDate);
    sessionStorage.setItem("photo2", this.placementlist[idvalue].photo2);
    sessionStorage.setItem("photo3", this.placementlist[idvalue].photo3);
    sessionStorage.setItem("photo4", this.placementlist[idvalue].photo4);
    sessionStorage.setItem("photo5", this.placementlist[idvalue].photo5);
  }
}

interface Placement {
  id: number,
  header: string,
  mainphoto: string,
  type: string,
  location: string,
  entity: string,
  size: string,
  fromDate: string,
  toDate: string,
  photo2: string,
  photo3: string,
  photo4: string,
  photo5: string,
}
```

Comment: вы слишком требовательны к angular, angular вообще ничего не делает, он не может отслеживать изменения в папке, это клиентский фреймворк, вебпак загружает все изображения в память, поэтому удаляете ли вы картинку либо добавляете, никто об этом не знает, а отслеживать изменения в папке с помощью `fs.watch` - слишком тяжелый процесс и медленный

Comment: @overthesanity, что же мне сделать, чтобы это исправить?

Comment: нужно дать вебпаку возможность узнать об этом файле и попытаться импортировать это изображение, типа `// @ts-ignore import * as image from './path-to.png'`, после рекомпиляции этот импорт можно убрать, так как изображение попадет в память

Comment: @overthesanity, https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-management/, эта статья решит мою задачу?